# assignments between loops be expressed as python comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Can the case of multiple ifs (like switch) or assignments between for loops be expressed as python comprehension (list comprehension) or any simplification?

The following three examples:

1.This function wants to insert the string into the list A

```
A= ["apple", 'banana', 'cat', 'duck', ...'n']
for i in [7, 3, 2, 1]:       

    if i == 1:   
        A.insert(i, A[i])   

    if i == 2 or i == 1:  
        A.insert(i, A[i])    

    A.insert(i, A[i])
```

The following two formulas want to do the function of word count:
2.

```
B= ["apple", 'banana', 'cat', 'duck', ...'n']
C = set(B)
    dic = {}
    for a in C:
        value = 0
        for wordCount in B:
            if a == wordCount:
                value = value + 1
        dic[a] = value

word_sorted = sorted(dic.keys())
values = list(dic.values())
```

3. 

```
    value_sorted = []
    for k in word_sorted:
        i = 0
        for k1 in dic.keys():
            if k == k1 :
                value_sorted.append(values[i])
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: Could you format your code with triple quotes so we have color syntaxing and  a better comprehension of the code.

Comment: what's the purpose of having two conditions inside 1.?

Comment: for 2.  use counter from collections to count occurences of words in that list    
                                                                                                                           
 `from collections import Counter`
`B= ["apple", 'banana', 'cat', 'duck','n']`

`Counter(B) `

Answer (score 0):

For the second example, if the goal is to count the amount of element in the array, you can do it with dictionnary comprehension like this :

```py
arr = ["apple", "banana", "cat", "duck", "duck"]
dic = { word: arr.count(word) for word in set(arr) }
print(dic) # {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'cat': 1, 'duck': 2}
```

On the third example, if the goal is to get the values of the dict sorted by the keys, you can use list comprenhension :

```py
dic = {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'cat': 1, 'duck': 2}
sorted_values =[dic[key] for key in sorted(dic.keys())]
print(sorted_values) # [2, 1, 1, 2]
```